# Style For Span Class Not Showing Up In Inspector Styles

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I wrapped a WordPress function, `.the_post_thumbnail().` inside of a span with class 'post-image', like this:

```
  echo "<span class='post-image'>".the_post_thumbnail()."</span>";
```

The style that I'm trying to apply is `width: 100%` to make the image take up 100% width of it's `<div>` / container. But when inspecting the post images in the browser, none of the post images are inheriting this style.

[image]

My CSS is simply:

```
.post-image {
    width: 100%!important;
}
```

This is the type of situation where I just don't know what else to try. I don't want to make any changes in reset.css because that would affect all other images - I'm just trying to style the images for the blog posts.

Comment: It is because `the_post_thumbnail()` already renders the image. Have you tried using `get_the_post_thumbnail()` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: (no need for *echo*, this function echo`s)

```
the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail');
```

Post thumbnails are given a class **wp-post-image** and also get a class depending on the size of the thumbnail being displayed. You can style the output with these CSS selectors:

```
img.wp-post-image
img.attachment-thumbnail
img.attachment-medium
img.attachment-large
img.attachment-full
```

You can also give post thumbnails their own class. Display the post thumbnail with a class **post-image**:

```
the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail', ['class' => 'post-image']);
```

Style it:

```
img.post-image {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `clear` css property.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clear